# C++ Doubly-linked list "delete tail" function

Tags: c++, doubly-linked-list, unordered, cyclic

I've already made singly-linked cyclic list, which worked fine, but in this case i'm encountering such problem, that if I want to remove tail, it will remove it, if the node was inserted as tail, but won't if it was inserted as head. I presume, the problem lies within inserthead-inserttail connection or delete tail function, but can't find it. I'll be grateful for you help.

Structure:

```
struct Element{
int value;
Element *prev, *next;
```

};

```
struct List2W{
    Element *tail;
};
```

Code:

```
void insertHead(List2W& l, int x){

Element *new_head = new Element;
new_head->value=x;

if(isEmpty(l))
{
    new_head->next=new_head;
    new_head->prev=new_head;
    l.tail=new_head;
}
else
{
    new_head->next=l.tail->next;
    new_head->prev=l.tail;
    l.tail->next=new_head;
}
```

}

```
void insertTail(List2W& l, int x){

Element *new_tail = new Element;
new_tail->value=x;

if(isEmpty(l))
{
    new_tail->next=new_tail;
    new_tail->prev=new_tail;
}
else
{
    new_tail->next=l.tail->next;
    new_tail->prev=l.tail;
    l.tail->next=new_tail;
}
l.tail=new_tail;
```

}

```
bool deleteTail(List2W& l, int &value){

if(isEmpty(l))
    return false;

else if(l.tail->next==l.tail)
    {
        value=l.tail->value;
        l.tail=NULL;
    }

else
{
    value=l.tail->value;
    (l.tail->prev)->next=l.tail->next;
    (l.tail->next)->prev=l.tail->prev;
    l.tail=l.tail->prev;
}
return true;}
```

Answer (score 0):

[image]

```
void insertTail(List2W& l, int x) {
    // a part is omitted
    new_tail->next = l.tail->next;
    new_tail->prev = l.tail;
    l.tail->next = new_tail;
    (l.tail->next)->prev = new_tail;  // is this unnecessary?
}
```

Comment: Wow, you even bothered to draw pictures. Thank you for that. I don't understand why you're saying that inserthead is impossible, though. I don't see any mistake there and it seems to work fine.

Could you, please, explain further why (1) won't work?
new_tail->next=l.tail->next; //for the "next" in new element i assign the same that was for the tail, which pointed to head, so after this new_tail->next should point to l.tail->next (which is head)

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so my inserthead function was missing a line, that should connect head's previous with new_head:

```
 else
    {
        (l.tail->next)->prev=new_head; // here
        new_head->next=l.tail->next;
        new_head->prev=l.tail;
        l.tail->next=new_head;
    }
```

Thank you @nariuji, you made me re-analize that function, and thanks for your interest. Other than that, I just need to take care of actually deleting the tail to free the memory and should be okay.